# How to generate ipa file using react native (visual studio code)

Tags: react-native

how to generate .ipa file in react native using visual studio code?

Thanks

Naresh

Answer (score 2):

Perform the below steps to generate IPA

1) In Appdeleget.m

In didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method, replace jsCodeLocation line with below line

jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

2) Prodct > Edit Scheme > Run > Build Configuration > Set Release mode

3) react-native bundle --platform ios --assets-dest ./ --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle

It will generate main.jsbundle and Assets folder . Go to your Xcode right click add files to project and add main.jsbundle file to project. Also drag and drop Assets folder and select create by reference (note: do not select create group).

4) Rest of the steps are same as like we are creating IPA for ios app.

Comment: Can you upload this IPA file to the App Store?

Answer (score -1):

Here's [a link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production) to the React Native documentation.

Basically, when you Archive the product from Xcode, it generates the IPA.